# Efficiency of Source.fromFile

Tags: scala

I wonder what is the efficiency of the following snippet:

```
val lst = Source.fromFile(f).getLines.toList
```

When issuing `lst.contains(x)`,

does it mean that `f` is being re-scanned, or is it the case that the search is relying on the in-memory content of `f` in the newly created list?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search is relying on in-memory contents. And it is only loaded once `toList` is called.

How better to see directly from the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/io/Source.scala#L1).  `Source.fromFile` returns a `scala.io.BufferedSource`. `getLines` returns a [BufferedLineIterator](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/io/BufferedSource.scala#L1).

It is here in BufferedLineIterator, the contents of the files is read.

```
override def hasNext = {
  if (nextLine == null)
    nextLine = lineReader.readLine

  nextLine != null
}
override def next(): String = {
  val result = {
    if (nextLine == null) lineReader.readLine
    else try nextLine finally nextLine = null
  }
  if (result == null) Iterator.empty.next
  else result
}
}
```

Calling `toList` uses the `next` and `hasNext` above to derive the list. So `lst` already contains all the elements of the File.

Doing `lst.contains(x)` iterates through the list as any other list.

Answer (score 2):

Once you use toList, it will return immutable list to you to operate on. your file will not be rescanned for operations you are doing on list you got